# (Math.random() * a); possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, int, double

In the code bellow on the line "int x = (Math.random() * a)" I get a error that says "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int" at "* a);"

```
`
import java.util.Scanner;
public class problem4 {
    public static void rollDice() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many random numbers should be generated?");
        int n = reader.nextInt();
        Scanner reader1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the number of values for each random draw?");
        int a = reader.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            int x = (Math.random()* a);
            System.out.println("Random number "+i+" is "+x+".");
}}}`
```

I am using Java in BlueJ.

Comment: So whats the question? Whats unclear with "possible lossy conversion from double to int"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.random` returns a `double`. Then you try to multiply that double by `a` and put it into an `int`.

An `int` is always a whole number (no decimal places). So it's telling you that you're losing those decimal places by doing that operation (putting it back into an `int`).

You could fix the problem by making `x` a `double`. Or if you actually want the whole numbers, you can explicitly cast the value of `x` to an `int` by doing: 
`int x = (int) (Math.random() * a)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()

```
Random r = new Random ();
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x ++) {
    System.out.println(r.nextInt());
}
```

or

```
System.out.println(r.nextInt(52)); to limit to a number
```

Comment: From the context, I think this is an assignment and he's supposed to be using `Math.random()`. In class, everything has to be done the long way.

Comment: so you downvote me for that?  The question does not mention **homework** at all

Comment: Fair point. downvote removed. :+1: